# How to square a directed Graph?

Tags: graph-theory

> The square of a directed graph $G = (V, E)$ is the graph $G^2 = (V, E^2)$ such that $(u,v) ∈ E^2$ if and only if $G$ contains a path with at most two edges between $u$ and $v$.

If I understand this correctly, then for example let graph $G$ be:

[image]

Adjacency-Matrix representation of $G$ would be:

[image]

then $G^2$ would be:

[image]

[image]

The above $G^2$ is a result of:

[image]

Comment: In your initial adjacency matrix, coordinate c,c should be 0. No loop on edge c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"At most" includes all previously passed through nodes, so it would rather be

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2}M^k \geq 1$$

An even simpler case $A \to B \to C$

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{array}\right)$$

You can probably see why squaring $M$ would not help getting each node as close to "at most" 2 steps away.